# Storing and fetching line-breaks in MySQL with PHP Data Objects

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm currently building a SQL database for articles with PHP. However when SELECTING and echoing the result set (which is fetched as an array with PDO) I can't seem to figure out how to echo out the result as html. I'm currently printing the result set out as plain text which makes it impossible to use html elements like **<br>** and **<p>**.

Is it common practice to print out content as HTML or is there another standardised way of solving this issue of not being able to paragraph your content.

This is in short how the code currently looks like in the file for the article page:

#### SELECTING AND FETCHING OF SQL

```
$sql = "SELECT a.content, a.id FROM articles AS a WHERE a.id = :id;";
$article = pdo($pdo, $sql, [$id])->fetch();
```

[...]

#### PRINTING OF RESULTS

```
<div>
    <p><?= html_escape($article['content']) ?></p>
</div>
```

The result of this will be that all text no matter how its written into the database will be in the same paragraph.

**EDIT:**

This is the user-defined function used to return PDO

```
function pdo(PDO $pdo, string $sql, array $arguments = null)
{
    $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);    
    $statement->execute($arguments);     
    return $statement;                   
}
```

Comment: If you want to display the text as written, put it in `<PRE>` tags, not `<P>` tags. If you simply want to maintain paragraphs, you might use `nl2br()`. If you want the author to have some more significant control over their desired formatting, you might accept [Markdown](https://www.markdownguide.org/) as input and then use a [3rd party renderer](https://github.com/thephpleague/commonmark) to convert that to HTML at display time.

Comment: Thanks very much, will take a look at all of thes provided alternatives.

Comment: Your problem isn't related to PHP or mysql. This is how **html** woks. Congrats on using the Jon Duckett's book, it's the right thing.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense! And yes, Jon Duckett's book have been great for a beginner - however I bought his JS/jQuery book which is the next one in line and apparently its supposed to be really outdated according to the internet unfortunately.